# How to color multiple lines based on their value?

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, matlab-figure

I produced a plot that contains 50 curves and each of them corresponds to a specific value of a parameter called "Jacobi constant", so I have 50 values of jacobi constant stored in array called `jacobi_cst_L1`:

```
   3.000900891023230
   3.000894276927840
   3.000887643313580
   3.000881028967010
   3.000874419173230
   3.000867791975870
   3.000861196034850
   3.000854592397690
   3.000847948043080
   3.000841330136040
   3.000834723697250
   3.000828099771820
   3.000821489088600
   3.000814922863360
   3.000808265737810
   3.000801695858850
   3.000795067776960
   3.000788475204760
   3.000781845363950
   3.000775192199620
   3.000768609354090
   3.000761928862980
   3.000755335851910
   3.000748750854930
   3.000742084743060
   3.000735532899990
   3.000728906460450
   3.000722309400740
   3.000715644446600
   3.000709016645110
   3.000702431180730
   3.000695791284050
   3.000689196186970
   3.000682547292110
   3.000675958537960
   3.000669315388860
   3.000662738391370
   3.000656116141060
   3.000649560630930
   3.000642857256680
   3.000636330415510
   3.000629657944820
   3.000623060310100
   3.000616425935580
   3.000609870077710
   3.000603171772120
   3.000596554947660
   3.000590018845460
   3.000583342259840
   3.000576748353570
```

I want to use a colormap to color my curves and then show in a lateral bar the legend that show the numerical values corresponding to each color of orbit.
[image]

By considering my example image, I would want to add the array of constants in the lateral bar and then to color each curve according the lateral bar.

```
% Family of 50 planar Lyapunov orbits around L1 in dimensionless unit
fig = figure;

for k1 = 1:(numel(files_L1_L2_Ly_prop)-2)
    plot([Ly_orb_filt(1).prop(k1).orbits.x],[Ly_orb_filt(1).prop(k1).orbits.y],...
        "Color",my_green*1.1); hold on  %"Color",my_green*1.1
    colorbar()
end
axis equal


% Plot L1 point
plot(Ly_orb_filt_sys_data(1).x,Ly_orb_filt_sys_data(1).y,'.',...
    'color',[0,0,0],'MarkerFaceColor',my_green,'MarkerSize',10);
text(Ly_orb_filt_sys_data(1).x-0.00015,Ly_orb_filt_sys_data(1).y-0.0008,'L_{1}');

%Primary bodies plots 
plot(AstroData.mu_SEM_sys  -1,0,'.',...
    'color',my_blue,'MarkerFaceColor',my_blue,'MarkerSize',20);
text(AstroData.mu_SEM_sys-1,0-0.001,'$Earth + Moon$','Interpreter',"latex"); 

grid on;
xlabel('$x$','interpreter','latex','fontsize',12);
ylabel('$y$','interpreter','latex','FontSize',12);
```

How can I color each line based on its Jacobi constant value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any colour map to produce a series of RGB-triplets for the plotting routines to read (Or create an *m-by-3* matrix with elements between `0` and `1` yourself):

```matlab
n = 10;  % Plot 10 lines
x = 1:15;
colour_map = jet(n);  % Get colours. parula, hsv, hot etc.

figure;
hold on
for ii = 1:n
    % Plot each line individually
    plot(x, x+ii, 'Color', colour_map(ii, :))
end

colorbar  % Show the colour bar.
```

Which on R2007b produces:

[image]

Note that indexing into a colour map will produce linearly spaced colours, thus you'll need to either interpolate or calculate a lot to get the specific ones you need. Then you can (need to?) modify the resulting colour bar's labels by hand to reflect your input values. I'd simply use `parula(50)`, treat its indices as `linspace(jacobi(1), jacobi(end), 50)` and then `my_colour = interp1(linspace(jacobi(1), jacobi(end), 50), parula(50), jacobi)`.

So in your code, rather than using `"Color",my_green*1.1` for each line, use `"Color",my_colour(kl,:)`, where `my_colour` is whatever series of RGB triplets you have defined.

Comment: Really? `jet`? Et tu, Adriaan?

Comment: Hi @Adriaan, can you tell me the difference between the following 1D interpolations?

1st interp. `my_color_map = interp1( jacobi_cst_L1 , parula(50), jacobi_cst_L1);`

2nd interp. `my_color_map = interp1(  linspace(jacobi_cst_L1(1), jacobi_cst_L1(end), 50  , parula(50), jacobi_cst_L1);
`.
Where `jacobi_cst_L1` is the array shown in my question.

Comment: @Giuseppe please ask a new question about that, see [ask].

Comment: @Adriaan it is a question stirctly related to my original question. It does not introduce any new topic.

Comment: Well, you're asking now about the difference between two interpolation techniques, rather than colouring lines. I'd beg to differ that that is indeed a different question. Anyway, you're missing a closing `)` in your second code at the `linspace()` call. Read the docs on `interp1` and `linspace` to see what the query and sample points are. As I said: `parula(50)` generates *linearly distributed* points, which your smaple points are not (presumably). Thus you need to interpolate your linear *sample* points to the *query* ones.

Comment: Thank you for answering. My points are quasi-linearly spaced (the difference bewteen two consecutive points is of order fo magnitude 10^-5), so is it better to use linspace or can I leave the original array?

Comment: That's up to you, you're the one creating, publishing and describing that figure. That said, a `10^-5` difference won't be noticeable to the human eye most likely and thus not add much for the figure. OTOH it does make it more "correct" and given you already have the code, there's not much reason not to use it. Anyway, try both and decide.